# How to check a yahoo email id is valid or not?

Tags: bash, email, yahoo

I am writing a script to find whether a email id is valid or not,but in the case of yahoo i can't telnet to yahoo. Any body have an idea about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Send an email to the address with a confirmation link.  If the user goes to that link, it's a valid email.  If not, it *might* be a valid email but hasn't been confirmed.  That's about all you can do.  How do you validate non-Yahoo! emails, such as Gmail?  Are you implying that you can telnet to Google and harvest email addresses from it?

Comment: @David: `telnet` is a misleading description. He means "a text protocol on a TCP port", in particular, SMTP. You can connect to GMails SMTP server and check if they accept mail for a given email address.

Comment: @MSalters in the case of yahoo.com they always shows id is valid but when we try to send mails that will be bounced :(

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/email-verify-bot

Answer (score -1):

You may send an verification code to email address and ask user to enter that code to your site for verification, if code match it is a valid email address.

There is no direct way to verify email address, as it can be use for spams.